# Right coordinates of a slanting line when slope is zero and left coordinates never changed after transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, linear-programming

I have a line in a program I am developing that I want to remove the slant (slope to zero) then get the new coordinates after transformation that removes the slope.

This is how the line with the slope looks like together with its coordinates 
(79, -131) and (158, -111)

This is the line without the slope ( when slope=0). How do I get the (x, y) coordinates after the transformation that changes it to a straight line at 180 degrees with no slope (slope = 0)? Note that I do not intend to change point (79,-131).

I will gladly appreciate all your help on this.

Comment: According to your comments: You should first calculate the length of line between the points (79, -131) and (158, -111). Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Yeah that't true. I know the line length should not change because even in a wheel the radius doesn't reduce when it rotates. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
y-y_A=\dfrac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}(x-x_A) \iff
y+131=\dfrac{-111+131}{158-79}\left(x-79\right)
$$

Now Add another line with the negative of the previous slope and passing through the  starting point of (79,-131).  This transformation will get you a line that has zero slope and runs through the starting point .

I think this is what you are asking for.

Edit:

Initial Length of the line = $\sqrt{20^2 + 79^2} = \sqrt{6641}$

Now to preserve the length Equate $(x-79) =  \sqrt{6641}$

$x= 160.4923$

The new coordiates are (160.4923, -131)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What will your new coordinates be assuming that the original line retained  its length even after transformation (when slope is 0)?

Comment: See the edit, I have given the coordiates of the new point.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand you have a line of equation:
$$
y-y_A=\dfrac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}(x-x_A) \iff
y+131=\dfrac{-111+131}{158-79}\left(x-79\right)
$$
where the slope is $m=\dfrac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A} =\dfrac{20}{79}$. If you want a new line with slope $0$ passing thorough the point $(79,-131)$ you can use the same formula with $m=0$ and you find
$$y+131=0 \iff y=-131$$.

If you want the point on this line corresponding to $x=158$ you have simply $(158,-131)$

Comment: thanks for your answer but  will your new line with slope 0 be the same length as the original line? I think in your case it will be lesser. I do not intend the length of the original line to reduce